# Excel-dna Add-in opens Excel in the background after closing Excel

Tags: excel-dna

I wrote an Add-In using Excel-DNA.
Testing it in different Excel Versions (2016,365 on different PC with Win 10) with Excel-Add-Ins getting the .xll
Works fine - but when Excel is closed, a hidden Excel Instance is created/kept? Which one has to be killed by task manager. (Or reopening Excel will not open with add-ins)

When I unload the add-in, Excel closes completely.

A strange thing is, that the Add-In is shown in the Excel Add-Ins also in the com Add-Ins

What could be the reason for that (mis)behaviour and how can I solve this.

Thankful for every advice

P.S.
ExcelDna 1.6.0, .Net Framework 4.7.2, vb.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that the Excel process is not terminating because there are outstanding COM references. From your Excel-DNA add-in, this can happen easily if you access the Excel COM object model from a thread that is not the main thread (`ManagedThreadId==1`). From an Excel-DNA add-in you should only ever access the COM object model from the main thread.

Some examples that cause problems would be:

- Using the COM object model inside an async function's 'inside' part.
- Having a timer callback from a threadpool thread where you do some work with the COM object model.
- Having some async work or a Task that calls the object model when it completes.

In some of these cases you can switch to the main thread in a context where it is safe to call the COM object model with a call to the Excel-DNA helper method `ExcelAsyncUtil.QueueAsMacro`. This can be called from any thread, and the code will execute as soon as Excel is available.

Comment: Thanks for these hints from Excel-DNA himself (brilliant framework anyway), I will work on them during this week (private development) 
I do not use async with excel . 
And there is no timer, but 2 culprits could be?:
In Autopen I set a SetWindowsHookEx which I release in AutoClose
Another one could be perhaps dynamic menus in the ribbon.
I will remove these parts experimentally.
There are a few Projects called by the DNA Project in the solution, but this should not be the problem, because the problem arises even without any action from the ribbon
I will tell about success..

Comment: Dynamic Menus should be fine. AutoClose is not called when Excel closes - only when the add-in is removed while Excel is still running.

Comment: At least the culprit is found. I think, I expected an Install and Uninstall Method and miss guessed AutoOpen and AutoClose.
So I have to go deeper into this - or has ExcelDNA an Event Excel Close / Excel Open or similar. Thank you again for your precious help.

Comment: Oh my, my stupidness is ...
It has nothing to do with the hook. I forgot, that I have a timer with Application Events on some Events like SheetActivate and they seem  not terminated (also they should).  Now I have to find out, why they are not terminated, not disposed. But this is my problem.
(And because I had the hook and the AppEvents in the AutoOpen ... oh if feel bad)

Comment: The problem won't be the event hooks, but if you do any COM work from the Timer callback, since the Timer callback happens on another thread. You can call ExcelAscynUtil.QueueAsMacro(...) from the Timer callback, and do the COM work there.

Comment: ExcelAscynUtil.QueueAsMacro seems to do the trick! I have to do some more tests. But thanks for the help again.
I think in the example on the Excel-DNA Site :https://excel-dna.net/docs/guides-advanced/async-macro-example-formatting-the-calling-cell-from-a-udf
there is an extra curly bracket  in the first code block.